# iOS - Update NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

wI am using three fetch controllers in order to filter three lists of tasks; today's, tomorrow's and finally later tasks. For that case, I have three predicates:

```
NSPredicate *todayPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date <= %@) AND isDone == 0",
                                   [self getEndDateForDay:P_Section_Today]];
NSPredicate *tomorrowPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)) AND isDone == 0",
                                   [self getStartDateForDay:P_Section_Tomorrow],
                                   [self getEndDateForDay:P_Section_Tomorrow]];
NSPredicate *laterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND isDone == 0",
                                      [self getStartDateForDay:P_Section_Later]];
```

I was happy with it. It worked like a charm. Until, over a night, I faced the following problem. The three controllers do not update themselves.

Example:
- Started the app on Sunday. (Now, today is Sunday.).
- The app is still running.
- Opened the app on Monday morning.
- Added a new task for Monday. It shall appear in Today's task, right? No!, it appears in Tomorrow's tasks. No fix for that except to close the app from the background and launch it again.

I did thought that the `performFetch` does update the fetch controller along with its predicate, but it doesn't. Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date in the predicates is fixed when you create them, i.e., your `getStartDateForDay:` and `getEndDateForDay:` will not get called again automatically. You need to update the predicates when you detect that the day has changed.

Comment: So, I need to keep tracking date changes like every second?

Comment: @ShatouDev Well, not necessarily, e.g., you could store the the current date when you create the predicates and then check always check if the date has changed when the application is reactivated from sleep or background. And if you need to update live when the user is actively using the app at midnight, you could set a timer to go off at midnight instead of actively polling the date. (Also consider how you want the user interface to behave; it might be not be good to automatically refresh if the user is doing something… perhaps there is some action you can tie the date check to?)

Comment: Personally I'd just check the date on app activation from background/sleep, and when the user does something that causes an update anyhow (e.g., creates/deletes/edits a task).

Comment: Using a timer for every second is really consuming. I will consider some of your solutions. Thanks Arkku. That was helpful.